# Overflow hidden not working during CSS rotate animation

Tags: animation, rotation, css

I have a parent div with a border-radius of 50% and the overflow is set to hidden. Within is a child div, which is animated.  As long as the rotation property of the child div is not animated, everything works fine - but as soon as I try to animate the child's rotation, the overflow:hidden of the parent div no longer works.

Below is an example - any help would be great!

I'm testing in Safari 7.0.1

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/etEAv

Comment: Confirmed on Safari 5.1.7 (Windows 7). Overflow:hidden works, but disregards the border-radius property. Seems like a Safari bug.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I came across the same problem. I don't think the bug has been fixed in Safari at all. I was able to fix my problem by adding a z-index to the overflow: hidden element. transform: translateZ(0); may also work. It seems like position:fixed also fixes the problem, but that might not work for as many situations. Hope this helps others for now.

Comment: I have a button with a pseudo-element nested inside, which animates from a width of 0 to 100% on hover to create a "filling" effect inside the button. The pseudo-element was overflowing outside of its container (which has rounded corners) only during the animation, and then would be properly contained within the parent at the end of the animation. Adding z-index to the parent element didn't work for me, but adding `transform: translateZ(0)` to the parent element worked like a charm with no other changes required.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, "adding a z-index to the overflow: hidden element." solved the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

This is a known Safari bug, and was reported [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=72619). It was marked as Resolved on 2012-11-14.

```
Comment #25 From Manolis Kp. 2012-11-14 02:07:14 PST
This issue has been fixed, marking as resolved
```

So you should be able to get the desired behavior when you update your Safari to the latest stable version.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I wish it were resolved, but I'm using Safari 7.0.1 on a Mac, which is the latest version - and I'm still having the issue.

Comment: Consider reopening the bug with your info. It will be resolved faster and has the added benefit of helping the community.

Comment: Will do. Waiting on the New Account verification email so that I can submit the information.